# Error: Could not find or load main class schemacrawler.Main

Tags: java, shell, jar, schemacrawler

I'm following the cross-platform installation instructions on osx.

I downloaded the latest .zip from the releases page. And do

```
$ cp -R _schemacrawler/ /usr/local/bin/
$ schemacrawler.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class schemacrawler.Main
```

what did I miss?

The contents of schemacrawler.sh are

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ':'):config schemacrawler.Main "$@"
```

My best guess is I need to place the necessary .jar files somewhere. Where should I place `schemacrawler-14.14.03.jar` and `schemacrawler-postgresql-14.14.03.jar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the shell script to

```
DIR=/usr/local/bin/
java -cp $(echo $DIR/lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ':'):config schemacrawler.Main "$@"
```

track the issue at https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/issues/115